# Extract first fields from struct columns into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, struct, field

I need to create a dictionary from Spark dataframe's schema of type `pyspark.sql.types.StructType`.

The code needs to go through entire `StructType`, find only those `StructField` elements which are of type `StructType` and, when extracting into dictionary, use the `name` of parent `StructField` as `key` while `value` would be `name` of only the **first** nested/child `StructField`.

Example schema (`StructType`):

```
root
|-- field_1: int
|-- field_2: int
|-- field_3: struct
|    |-- date: date
|    |-- timestamp: timestamp
|-- field_4: int
```

Desired result:

```py
{"field_3": "date"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension navigating through the schema.

```py
{x.name: x.dataType[0].name for x in df.schema if x.dataType.typeName() == 'struct'}
```

---

Test #1

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([], 'field_1 int, field_2 int, field_3 struct<date:date,timestamp:timestamp>, field_4 int')

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- field_1: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- field_2: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- field_3: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- date: date (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- field_4: integer (nullable = true)

{x.name: x.dataType[0].name for x in df.schema if x.dataType.typeName() == 'struct'}
# {'field_3': 'date'}
```

Test #2

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([], 'field_1 int, field_2 struct<col_int:int,col_long:long>, field_3 struct<date:date,timestamp:timestamp>')

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- field_1: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- field_2: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- col_int: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- col_long: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- field_3: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- date: date (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)

{x.name: x.dataType[0].name for x in df.schema if x.dataType.typeName() == 'struct'}
# {'field_2': 'col_int', 'field_3': 'date'}
```

Comment: One of the most elegant ways I've seen! Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried to add one more `field_5 choice<date:date,timestamp:timestamp>` field but getting an error: `mismatched input '<' expecting {<EOF>, '(', ',', 'COMMENT', NOT}(line 1, pos 100)`

Comment: Your syntax is off. `field_5 choice<date:date,timestamp:timestamp>` - instead of `choice` you should tell the data type, so it should be `struct`, like this: `field_5 struct<date:date,timestamp:timestamp>`

Comment: That might be caused by wrangling my dataset between spark and glue context...